# Overlaping a div without using z-index

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I ran into this problem which I can not seem to figure out, I was thinking of some CSS magic
but what would be the best approach to this problem?

I have this Progressbar component that has the ideal zone and also the actual progress bar. When the progress bar overlaps with the ideal zone I want to hide the ideal zone, just like it had a smaller z value, tried it and realized z-index does not work on statically placed elements, how can I replicate this behavior? Here is the component, it also uses tailwind for styling.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

type ProgressbarProps = {
  value: number,
  maxValue: number,
  percentageCap: number,
  idealZone: number
};

function Progressbar({ value, maxValue, percentageCap, idealZone }: ProgressbarProps) {
  const [displayedPercentage, setDisplayedPercentage] = useState(0);
  
  const idealZoneStart = 100 - idealZone/2;
  const idealZoneEnd = 100 + idealZone/2;

  useEffect(() => {
    const actualPercentage = (value / maxValue) * 100;
    setDisplayedPercentage(Math.min(percentageCap, actualPercentage)); 
  }, [value, maxValue]);

  const progressBarColor =
    displayedPercentage < idealZoneStart
      ? 'bg-orange-500'
      : displayedPercentage > idealZoneEnd
      ? 'bg-red-500'
      : 'bg-green-500';


  const progressBarStyle = {
    width: `${(displayedPercentage / percentageCap) * 100}%`,
  };

  const idealZoneStyle = {
    left: `${(idealZoneStart / percentageCap) * 100}%`,
    width: `${((idealZoneEnd - idealZoneStart) / percentageCap) * 100}%`, 
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <div className={`h-4 rounded ${progressBarColor}`} style={progressBarStyle}></div>
    <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-4 bg-gray-200" style={idealZoneStyle}></div>
    </div>
  );
}    

export default Progressbar;
```

Comment: "When the progress bar overlaps with the ideal zone I want to hide it" – What do you mean by "it" here? The progress bar or the ideal zone? Could you provide an example of usage of this component please? Perhaps with details about when it does not display as you'd like.

Comment: @Wongjn the ideal zone, I want the same functionality that a classic z-index would give

Comment: Could you provide an example of usage of this component please? Perhaps with details about when it does not display as you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> realized z-index does not work on statically placed elements

Just make the statically placed elements relatively positioned to make them behave like statically placed ones except they'll now respect z-index.

Example:

```css
.foo {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure if this will answer your questions. But try this:

1. **CSS Selectors and Styling:**

   Start by defining the necessary CSS selectors and styling rules. Assuming your component's container has the class `.progressbar-container`, you can use the adjacent sibling (`+`) selector to target the ideal zone and apply styles to hide it when the progress bar overlaps:

   ```css
   /* Using the adjacent sibling (+) selector to target the ideal zone */
   .progressbar-container .h-4 + .bg-gray-200 {
     display: none; /* Hide the ideal zone element */
   }

   /* You can also define a class to apply when the overlap condition is met */
   .overlap {
     /* Apply styles to show/hide the ideal zone as needed */
   }
   ```
2. **Component Implementation:**

   In your React component implementation, you can utilize the concept of the `.overlap` class to control the behavior of the ideal zone based on the overlapping condition:

   ```
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

   type ProgressbarProps = {
     value: number,
     maxValue: number,
     percentageCap: number,
     idealZone: number
   };

   function Progressbar({ value, maxValue, percentageCap, idealZone }: ProgressbarProps) {
     const [displayedPercentage, setDisplayedPercentage] = useState(0);

     const idealZoneStart = 100 - idealZone / 2;
     const idealZoneEnd = 100 + idealZone / 2;

     useEffect(() => {
       const actualPercentage = (value / maxValue) * 100;
       setDisplayedPercentage(Math.min(percentageCap, actualPercentage));
     }, [value, maxValue]);

     const progressBarColor =
       displayedPercentage < idealZoneStart
         ? 'bg-orange-500'
         : displayedPercentage > idealZoneEnd
         ? 'bg-red-500'
         : 'bg-green-500';

     const progressBarStyle = {
       width: `${(displayedPercentage / percentageCap) * 100}%`,
     };

     return (
       <div className={`relative ${displayedPercentage >= idealZoneStart && displayedPercentage <= idealZoneEnd ? 'overlap' : ''}`}>
         <div className={`h-4 rounded ${progressBarColor}`} style={progressBarStyle}></div>
         <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-4 bg-gray-200"></div>
       </div>
     );
   }

   export default Progressbar;
   ```

By conditionally applying the `.overlap` class to the component's container based on the overlap condition, the adjacent sibling selector in the CSS will hide the ideal zone when the progress bar overlaps it. When the condition is not met, the ideal zone will be displayed as intended.

Comment: It does work too, but the other solution is much simpler, thanks